# Should the "tradename" tag be merged with "trade-name"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

<strike>The [tradename](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradename) tag requires a hyphen to separate the two words.</strike>

I'm not sure whether it can done by a Mod's edit, or a new tag needs creating and merging..?

Revised following the creation of a new tag:

Can the [tradename](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradename) tag be merged with [trade-name](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trade-name) as a synonym, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had thought that a single word "tradename" was correct, but according to

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_name
- https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trade-name
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade%20name
- https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Tradename
- https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/120415/trade-name-vs-trademark-know-difference.asp
- https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/a-trade-name
- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/trade-name
- https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/trade_name
- https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trade-name

the two-word form is strongly preferred. But perhaps one should be a tag synonym of the other?

Comment: Re: your tag:synonym suggestion, there wasn't a hyphenated trade-name tag until [DaleM created one](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81363/35069) after I posted this question! But, yes, I see the logic in merging them